# fstream not creating a file with a asctime value appened to the file name

Tags: c++, io

I have already debug this down to the point I know the issue, I just do not know how to solve it.

Right now I am using:

```
file.open(logFile.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
```

the logFile variable works fine as long as I comment out the marked line below:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
logFile = "bin/";
if(_DEBUG) { logFile += "Debug/"; }
else { logFile += "Release/"; }
logFile += fileName;
if(_DEBUG) { logFile += "Debug-"; }
else { logFile += "Release-"; }
logFile += asctime(timeinfo); // Works fine with this line commented.
logFile += ".log";
```

So how can I get this to work right with this line uncommented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon (`:`) is an illegal character for file names, at least for NTFS. Try using [`strftime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) instead to format a string that doesn't include the colons.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a guess. Adding the time to your file name will add colons to it, 12:23:34 for instance. I'm guessing you are on a file system where it's not legal to use colons in a file name.

Solution (if my guess is right), replace the colons with underscores or similar.